# SQL Server - Simple multiple choice field definition

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server, coming from a MySQL background. I am trying to migrate a MySQL table that contains several fields defined similarly to the following one:

```
"FavoriteColors" SET('Red','Blue','Dark Purple', 'Green') DEFAULT NULL,
```

Basically, they are multiple-choice questions. When entering these fields in a form, the user will be able to select one or more of them.

When looking for a SQL Server equivalent to this definition, I have seen that many people create an extra table for the different choices, and then a lookup table to connect the two previous ones. Knowing that there are several multiple-choice fields like this one, it seems a pretty complicated solution for such a simple definition. Is this really best practices, or do you recommend an alternate solution? Of course, I can use BIT fields for each of the choices, but again, it seems to me that SQL Server probably has a simpler, better organized solution for this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Creating another table to hold options (with a foreign key) is just normalising the database, which is standard database practice. It looks like the MySQL syntax above is similar to a CHECK CONSTRAINT in SQL, but a check constraint does not impose any values in a user interface, it just throws a database error if an invalid value is entered. I see from the MySQL SET doco that you can do a system catalog hack to retrieve the possible SET values - is that what you are doing? You could do probably do something similar in SQL Server but it is recommended that you normalise out to another table

Comment: Great, thank you so much to both!

Answer (score 0):

You can create user-defined type and create a rule for this data type. This enables you use this new data type everywhere in your database

Here is the code, please execute step by step

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Color] FROM [nvarchar](40) NULL

CREATE RULE ruleColor
AS
(@phone='Red') OR 
(@phone='Black')
GO

EXEC sp_bindrule 'ruleColor', 'Color'
```

I hope it helps,

Comment: Note: This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. We recommend that you use check constraints instead. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188064.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for information, I did not realize that there is a such plan

Comment: Thanks to both for the comments!